# GridView (Aspx)(CSV) Data is not displayed correctly in the rows

Tags: c#, asp.net

The data is not displayed correctly in the columns.
The CSV consists of 7 columns. Rows are of different length.
I can not upload a picture.(https://ibb.co/0fnfLW7)

```
        DataTable tblcsv = new DataTable();
        tblcsv.Columns.Add("Vorname");
        tblcsv.Columns.Add("Nachname");
        tblcsv.Columns.Add("RFID");
        
          string csvData = File.ReadAllText(csvPath);
        //spliting row after new line  
        foreach (string csvRow in csvData.Split(';'))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(csvRow))
            {
                //Adding each row into datatable  
                tblcsv.Rows.Add();
                int count = 0;
                foreach (string FileRec in csvRow.Split(';'))
                {
                    tblcsv.Rows[tblcsv.Rows.Count - 1][count] = FileRec;
                    count++;

                    for(var x=0; x<7; x++)
                    {
                        //tblcsv[x][count] = FileRec;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }
            //Calling Bind Grid Functions  
            BindgridStaffImport(tblcsv);
        }
```

Comment: Can you show some of the input and also give us an idea what the current output looks like? It will make it easier to spot the problem

Comment: Use Stream Reader : StreamReader csvData = new StreamReader(csvPath);  Then use From : foreach (string csvRow in csvData.Split(';')), To : While((string csvRow = csvData.ReadLine()) != null)

Answer (score 0):

You split code is using ";", and should it not be "," if a csv?

The code will look much like this:

```
        foreach (string csvRow in csvData.Split(';'))
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(csvRow))
            {
                //Adding each row into datatable  
                DataRow MyNewRow = tblcsv.NewRow();
                int count = 0;
                foreach (string FileRec in csvRow.Split(','))
                {
                    MyNewRow[count] = FileRec;
                    count++;
                }
                tblcsv.Rows.Add(MyNewRow);
            }
            //Calling Bind Grid Functions  
            BindgridStaffImport(tblcsv);
```

So, use the "newRow" method to create a new blank row based on the table. Set the column values, and then add this new row to the rows collection of the table.

And even better is to use the TextFieldParser class.

So,

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
```

And then you can even assume say the first row has the colum names.

This:

We assume you read the csv file into stirng sFileLocal

```
        // process csv file
        TextFieldParser MyParse = new TextFieldParser(sFileLocal);
        MyParse.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
        MyParse.SetDelimiters(new string[] { "," });
        MyParse.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;

        // add colums to table.

        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        foreach (string cCol in MyParse.ReadFields())
        {
            rstData.Columns.Add(cCol);
        }
        while (!MyParse.EndOfData)
        {
            string[] OneRow = MyParse.ReadFields();
            rstData.Rows.Add(OneRow);
        }
        // Now display results in a grid
        GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Quite much all above is you need.

Comment: Thank you very much for the support. 
I now have a working variant.
However, the goal is to skip the first line, the header.
Are there any ideas how I can implement this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the support.
I now have a working variant.
However, the goal is to skip the first line, the header.
Are there any ideas how I can implement this.

```
  List<string> headercolumns = new List<string> { "Vorname", "Nachname",  };
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                foreach (string header in headercolumns)
                {
                    
                    dt.Columns.Add(header);
                }

                List<string> StaffList = new List<string>();
                using (StreamReader filereader = new StreamReader(StaffFileUpload.FileContent))
                {
                    
                    string readline = string.Empty;
                    while ((readline = filereader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                       
                        StaffList.Add(readline);
                    }
                    if (StaffList != null && StaffList.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (string info in StaffList)
                        {
                            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                            string[] mitarbeiter = info.Split(';');

                            for (int i = 0; i < mitarbeiter.Length; i++)
                            {
                                row[i] = mitarbeiter[i];
                            }
                            dt.Rows.Add(row);
                        }
                    }
                }
```